# Hat Matrix of Beta Regression

Tags: r, regression, glm, beta, hat

I am trying to calculate beta regression by using Hat matrix, manually. I am using idea of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/how-to-calculate-the-hat-matrix-for-logistic-regression-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1 answer. But its not working for me. Further, I am not sure its correct or not. Kindly help.
**My code**

```
  require(betareg)
df<-data("ReadingSkills")
y<-ReadingSkills$accuracy
n<-length(y)
x1<-rnorm(n,0,1)
x2<-rnorm(n,0,1)

X<-cbind(1,x1, x2)


bfit <- solve(t(X) %*% X + u * diag(3)) %*% t(X) %*% y
bfit1<-betareg(accuracy ~ x1+x2, data = ReadingSkills, link="logit")
bfit
bfit1

v <- 1/(1+exp(-X%*%bfit))
VX <- X*v 
H <- VX%*%solve(crossprod(VX,VX),t(VX))
```

Comment: yes and I want coefficients manually.

Comment: I dont think so my problem is as much complicated....check my referred link.

Comment: In the link they are interested in the Hat matrix and not the coefficients. You are interested in the coefficients. Two separate problems

Comment: nxt i want hat matrix. But I am stuck on starting point.

Comment: issue of Hat matrix is solved.  But still want to understand how you make a link function?

Comment: Check the code below and you will see that I used the `logit` link function for beta and the `log` link function for `phi`.

Comment: If I want to change link for betas thn.....?

Comment: Use a different function. Eg if you want probit, use `pnorm` instead of the `plogis`. Seems to me that the code i gave is of no help to you. Note that you first need to learn the distributions, then learn R extensively.  I do have free R for learning R you could attend. I can hell you with R.

Comment: thankq very much. But at which plate form???

Comment: Seems you did not even look at the solution. One thing. You need to start learning R. thats all i can say for now.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is best suited for cross validated as it requires math equations for the proofs. But we can still do the code here. Anyway, since your interest is the coefficients, it is worthwile to not that just like `logistic regression`, `betareg` does not have a closed form solution for the MLEs. You need to use any iterative methods for optimization. Below I use the readily available `optim` function from base R.

```
y<-ReadingSkills$accuracy
set.seed(1)
n<-length(y)
x1<-rnorm(n,0,1)
x2<-rnorm(n,0,1)
X<-cbind(1,x1, x2)



bfit1<-betareg(accuracy ~ x1+x2, data = ReadingSkills, link="logit")

bfit1

Call:
betareg(formula = accuracy ~ x1 + x2, data = ReadingSkills, 
    link = "logit")

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
    1.30730      0.28936     -0.08727  

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
(phi)  
3.409
```

Can we do the same directly without depending on the `betareg` function? Yes of course. we just write the log likelihood function and optimize that for the 4 parameters, ie the 3 betas, and the phi coefficient:

```
ll <- function(par){
  mu <- c(plogis(X %*% head(par, -1)))
  phi <- tail(par, 1)
  -sum(dbeta(y, mu*phi, (1-mu)*phi, log = TRUE))
}

optim(runif(ncol(X) + 1),ll)

$par
[1]  1.30733153  0.28936064 -0.08723266  3.40954180

$value
[1] -27.84788

$counts
function gradient 
     169       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

You can see that the results from `optim` match exactly what we have in beta regression.

Comment: thanks u hve solved my 1st problem bt i didn't understand the code. Its necessary coz nxt I hve to make this ridge by adding shrinkage parameter. Kindly plz define at which stage that will be added.

Comment: @JAK The code simply computes the beta regressionparameters. First I wrote a log likelihood taking into consideration the logit link then I maximized it to obtain the MLEs. Please note that if at any point the code seems difficult, then you need to learn the theory behind beta regression and even learn more about R. Notice that I only used BASE R meaning the code should be straight forward.

Comment: If I want to make this Ridge thn @ which point I 'll add shirinkge parameter? plus is my 3 liner code for H is correct or not?

Comment: @Ridge is a linear regression with L2 penalty. Seems to me that you need more of statistics background to understand the difference. Use `glmnet` package to run ridge regression. No you should not mix ridge and beta regressions.

Comment: I want to mix ridge and Beta, which is not available in glmnet. coz my main task is H matrix of beta with ridge.

Comment: @JAK is this a research thing you are doing? Well i have never heard of that. Probably someone else will help you